# Recursively remove children from parent based on a condition

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, mapping

I have a data that looks like this:

```json
{
  "fileObjects": [
    {
      "type": "DIRECTORY",
      "name": "st",
      "fileObjects": [
        {
          "type": "DIRECTORY",
          "name": "ko",
          "fileObjects": [
            {
              "type": "DIRECTORY",
              "name": "ve",
              "fileObjects": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "FILE",
      "name": "ac"
    },
    {
      "type": "DIRECTORY",
      "name": "rf",
      "fileObjects": [
        {
          "type": "DIRECTORY",
          "name": "lo",
          "fileObjects": [
            {
              "type": "FILE",
              "name": "we",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to filter recursively empty directories, simply getting rid of them:

```json
{
  "fileObjects": [
    {
      "type": "FILE",
      "name": "ac"
    },
    {
      "type": "DIRECTORY",
      "name": "rf",
      "fileObjects": [
        {
          "type": "DIRECTORY",
          "name": "lo",
          "fileObjects": [
            {
              "type": "FILE",
              "name": "we",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My attempt:

```js
function mapFileObject(fileObject) {
  if (fileObject.type === "FILE") {
    return fileObject;
  }

  return {
    ...fileObject,
    fileObjects: fileObject.fileObjects
      .filter((fileObjectChild) => {
        return fileObjectChild.fileObjects.length > 0;
      })
      .map((fileObjectChild) => mapFileObject(fileObjectChild)),
  };
}

const newFileObjects = {
  fileObjects: input.fileObjects.map((fileObjectChild) =>
    mapFileObject(fileObjectChild)
  ),
};
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clean(obj) {
  if (obj.type === 'FILE') {
    return obj
  }

  if (obj.type === 'DIRECTORY' && obj.fileObjects.length === 0) {
    return null
  }

  const fileObjects = obj.fileObjects.map(o => clean(o)).filter(o => o)

  return fileObjects.length ? { ...obj, fileObjects } : null
}

console.log(clean(data)) // data is the root object in your description.
```